# Stuck with multi click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I am stuck with the following. I have a play button. When the user clicks the first time on it, it should play the song and add a pause button to it. The second time you click on the button, it should pause the song.

Came up with this:

```
$('.play').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var trackID = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-id');
        console.log(trackID);

        $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 


        if ( $(this).hasClass('play pause') ) {
            console.log('false');
            $(this).removeClass('pause');
        } else {
            console.log('true');
            $(this).addClass('pause');
            //return false;
        }

        if (nowPlaying) {
            nowPlaying.stop();
        }


        SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID, function(sound) {
            if ( !$(this).hasClass('play pause') ) {
                console.log('hellooo');
                sound.play();
                nowPlaying = sound;
            } else {
                console.log('byeee');
                sound.pause();
                nowPlaying = sound;
            }
        });

   });
```

The above part will work correct. Play is the default of the button. When click the `console.log` send me the trackID: `91298058`, true, and the string `hellooo` inside the stream function and the song is playing. The second time it will give me also the trackID `91298058`, false and also the string `hellooo`. So the bug is here. Whenever you click the string `hellooo` will be send to the `console.log`. And the `console.log` - `byeee` will never be send and thus never be paused.

So in short, I would like to have one button that switch from play to pause and reverse. At play it should play the song: `sound.play();` and at pause it should pause the song: `sound.pause();`;

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1mnfn3ro/7/)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the callback function passed to `SC.stream`, `$(this)` is redefined.

You should cache it in the function attached to the click event, and use it after.

```
$('.play').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this);

    // the code

    SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID, function(sound) {
        if ( button.hasClass('play pause') ) {
            console.log('hellooo');
            sound.play();
            nowPlaying = sound;
        } else {
            console.log('byeee');
            sound.pause();
            nowPlaying = sound;
        }
    });
```

Also, you can just check for the class `pause` being present, instead of `play pause`.

Comment: Thank you. It works reverse. So When click on play it will pause the song and if click pause it will play the song. You should remove the exclamation mark to get it right work.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following work-around:
Create a boolean inside the click function and call it `bool`. Default is `false;`.

It is very similar to above code of @Colin Delhalle.

```
$('.play').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var trackID = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-id');
        console.log(trackID);

        $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 

        var bool = false;

        if ( $(this).hasClass('play pause') ) {
            console.log('false');
            bool = false;
            $(this).removeClass('pause');
        } else {
            console.log('true');
            $('#playlist li a').removeClass('pause');
            $(this).addClass('pause');
            bool = true;
        }

        if (nowPlaying) {
            nowPlaying.stop();
        }

        SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID, function(sound) {
            if (bool) {
                console.log('play');
                sound.play();
                nowPlaying = sound;
            } else {
                console.log('pause');
                sound.pause();
                nowPlaying = sound;
            }
        });

    });
```

The only thing I think is very strange, is that the function pause doesn't pause the song, but stop it.. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score -2):

Can you try to comment this line?

```
            SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID, function(sound) {
                if ( !$(this).hasClass('play pause') ) {
                    console.log('hellooo');
                    sound.play();
                    nowPlaying = sound;
                } else {
                    console.log('byeee');
                    sound.pause();
                    // nowPlaying = sound;
                }
            });
```

Comment: It looks like it does the same... Nothing different with my code.